# Rails 3 route Type Mismatch Error when requesting url for route with subdomain in Mailer view

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, routes, actionmailer, mailer

I'm getting this error when requesting this route: `direct_appointment_url(@appointment.uuid, :subdomain => @user.name)`

```
direct_appointment_url(@appointment.uuid, :subdomain => @user.name)
TypeError: can't convert Array to String
from ...rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p362@example/gems/actionpack-3.2.12/lib/action_dispatch/http/url.rb:55:in `match'
```

route is defined as: `get "/appointment/:uuid" => "schedule#appointment", as: "direct_appointment"`

The values of the two vars passed in to the route matcher are:

`appointment.uuid => "a52aff80-5b83-0130-987f-0026080ebf68"`

and

`@user.name => "example"`

More context:

```
ActionView::Template::Error (can't convert Array to String):
    13: Message: <%= @appointment.client_message %>
    14: <% end %>
    15:
    16: View online: <%= direct_appointment_url(@appointment.uuid, :subdomain => @user.name) %>
    17:
    18: To see your latest appointments, login at: <%= @login_url %>
    19: Your username is: <%= @user.email %>
  app/views/user_mailer/new_appointment_email.text.erb:16:in `_app_views_user_mailer_new_appointment_email_text_erb__686277782469675039_70200502266100'
  app/mailers/user_mailer.rb:13:in `block in new_appointment_email'
  app/mailers/user_mailer.rb:12:in `new_appointment_email'
  app/controllers/appointments_controller.rb:43:in `block in create'
  app/controllers/appointments_controller.rb:42:in `create'
```

Answer (score 0):

Ah, so much for useful error messages!

looking at the source code for `https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/actionpack/lib/action_dispatch/http/url.rb` at line 55, (although blank) the previous lines show the error that should have been raised:

```
if options[:host].blank? && options[:only_path].blank?
  raise ArgumentError, 'Missing host to link to! Please provide the :host parameter, set default_url_options[:host], or set :only_path to true'
end
```

once I specified a host, it worked:

> direct_appointment_url(@appointment.uuid, :subdomain => "hello", :host
>   => "blah")
>   => "http://hello.blah/appointment/6a5cc9a0-5b8f-0130-9883-0026080ebf68"

#### Protip

Don't provide an array of possible hosts to your config file:
`config.action_mailer.default_url_options = { :host => ['lvh.me:3000', 'blah.dev'] }`